# Should I correct my previous statement to a stranger after several years?

Tags: etiquette, email, communication

A stranger sent me an email asking for a solution and advice on a technical problem years ago. I gave him my personal opinon and solution at that time. Now, several years later, I found that some of my previous points were wrong and misleading. Should I send another email to correct my points after all those years? He is a stranger and we haven't been in communication since then.

Comment: Would it be much of a burden to you to write it?

Comment: @user111388 Not at all, I'm willing to provide better and more accurate solutions for him, but I don't know whether it will feel strange for him, because it's a topic alost 5 years ago, I don't even know if he is still using that email address.

Comment: Maybe you start with an email asking whether he would be interested in some updates given that in the meantime you found that your old answers were not optimal.

Comment: @konchy: I doubt anyone will find this strange. If it is much work for you, ask beforehand if they still need it..otherwise, just write!